# LINQ - Remove Parts of Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var query = session.Query<Event>()
    .Fetch(e => e.Venue); // Fetch is an IQueryable extension which does a join

// Code needed here to remove the fetch part

var num = query.Count(); // This then hits the database
```

Unfortunately this throws an error as fetch is not supported for a count method. At this stage i'm sure you're thinking why don't i remove the fetch part. However i have simplified my example and this is not possible. What i'd ideally like to be able to do is navigate the expression tree for the LINQ query and remove any calls to Fetch before i call Count.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show how this is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change expression trees at runtime (by building a new one out of the existing one), since O/RM tools such as LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework do this constantly, but it's not really easy. It has become easier with the introduction of the `ExpressionVisitor` class of .NET 4.0, but still don't expect it to be simple.

Here is an [article](http://rogeralsing.com/2010/11/10/entity-framework-4-enum-support-in-linq/) that shows an example of this.

Comment: Thanks but while i understand how i could use that to create my own Count extension method, i wouldn't have a clue how to write the ExpressionVisitor class to remove any calls to Fetch in the current expression.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to convert the query to an Enumerable and call Count() on this like this:

```
var num = query.AsEnumerable().Count();
```

This would execute the query and afterwards makes a simple Count() on the result instead of letting the Count() flow into the ExpressionTree.

Comment: Thanks but the trouble with this approach is that it will grab all the data from the database before doing a count which makes it incredibly slow for a large table.

Comment: @nfplee: Yes, i already thought that this would happen, but unfortunately i don't have any better idea. :-(